# Resharper Localization Name Variables

Tags: c#, resharper

I am using ReSharper 8 to help me in Localizing my Project. By Default ReSharper only has 3 variables which can be used to generate the name for the String to Localize:

```
$TypeName$,
$MemberName$,
$Value$
```

Is there any way I can add a $NameSpace$ variable?

I have checked the Documentation and there is no 'How to' but only a 'It's Possible'.

You can find this in `ReSharper > Options > Code Editing > Localization`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ReSharper has only this 3 variables and nothing else. You can add a feature request in the ReSharper issue tracker: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RSRP